# Group lines by line pattern

Tags: python

I have a file with lines that look like this:

```
saldkfjaslk
    asdlkfja
    alsdkfjlk
aslkda;kdfsdlkfaj
sladkfjalskdfjlaskd
    sldkfaj
    lsadkfj
qwewrewst
se0polkjlkj
lpoerlwoej
    alskdjf
    asldkfjljlkjlk
sadlkfa
```

I'd like to group together lines that start with a character (not whitespace) with consequitive lines that start with whitespace. I'd also like to omit lines where the next line does not start with whitespace. The desired output using the above example woud look like this:

```
[('saldkfjaslk', 'asdlkfja', 'alsdkfjlk'),
 ('sladkfjalskdfjlaskd', 'sldkfaj', 'lsadkfj'),
 ('lpoerlwoej', 'alskdjf', 'asldkfjljlkjlk')]
```

How can I parse this file in Python?

Comment: Looks like config parsing - if so, consider ready libraries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"^\S.*(?:\n\s.*)+", re.MULTILINE)
>>> [tuple(match.split()) for match in regex.findall(s)]
[('saldkfjaslk', 'asdlkfja', 'alsdkfjlk'), 
 ('sladkfjalskdfjlaskd', 'sldkfaj', 'lsadkfj'), 
 ('lpoerlwoej', 'alskdjf', 'asldkfjljlkjlk')]
```

**Explanation:**

```
^    # Start of line
\S   # Match a non-whitespace character
.*   # Match the rest of the line
(?:  # Match...
 \n  #  a newline character
 \s  #  a whitespace character
 .*  #  and the rest of the line
)+   # once or more
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use groupby, didn't think of regex for some reason.